# Meteor new application structure is slow down development for ui folder

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have migrated my **meteor 1.2.1** code base to **meteor 1.3.0** and also moved all client code to *imports/ui* to utilize lazy loading feature for imports folder.
My problem is, If I am changing any client side file its restarting every time, which slows down development time in meteor 1.3.0 as I have to wait for building process.

Please provide your suggestion or best approach to overcome this issue.

Comment: It does trigger a rebuld, as it doesn't know if the file is included or not. If I am editing several files, I defer my save until I am ready to test my changes, and save all the files at the same time.

Comment: afaik imports are *not* loaded lazily, just "conditionally." See [Understanding the Imports Directory](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/understanding-the-imports-directory/)

Answer (score 1):

As I have used Meteor 1.3.0 imports directory structure I have faced that issue but below are solution.

- I am posting answer to my question as I have found reason why Meteor rebuilding  my client side code, When I change any file.
- Currently I am using **/imports/ui/** for storing client side code. As you all know ***ui*** directory doesn't have any special purpose in Meteor build.
- So, it assume this code as client or server code and rebuild and restart meteor app every time.
- If you rename that folder/directory to ***client*** then it only refresh client side code not full app because ***client*** folder have special meaning in meteor.

Moreover now you can also use latest version of meteor which help to speed up startup building your app.

Hope this will help you solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 1.4.2 is been released in these days.

In the official forum they say: [The big news is improved rebuild performance](https://forums.meteor.com/t/announcing-meteor-1-4-2-rebuild-performance-and-a-look-ahead/30764).
Maybe you should give a try.